# Primefaces - How to show different messages in different messages component in the same form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need your assistant in showing the error messages in the proper messages component. In the form, I am using the messages component tag twice. The first messages component tag which is called messages, I am showing any error to the user that is validated from the main form.

Where I am also having a dialog in the same form that will validate if a variable is blank or empty, if it is blank,the error message should be shown in the messagesPDFST which is in the `dialog` not in the main form. Currently any error it is shown in the first messages component which is messages even if the error is in the `dialog`. Here is the code:

```
<h:form id="Requests">

    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>

     <p:dialog id="Certificate1" header="Certificate" widgetVar="Certificate1" modal="true">

          <div align="right">
              <p:messages id="messagesPDFST" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

               <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" actionListener="#{hrd.PDFSTAR}" >

                    <p:fileDownload value="#{hrd.fileSTAR}" />
                </p:commandButton>

         </div>

</p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

and the Bean Code:

```
public void PDFSTAR() {
     if (refNo== null || refNo.equals("")) {

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Please enter the Reference No."));

            }

}
```

Comment: Check and read the PrimeFaces documentation. There is a `for` attribute on the `p:messages`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display a `FacesMessage` for a specific component, you first need to

1. Queue the message, for the specific component:

   ```
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Please enter the Reference No."));
   ```

   The first argument where you have `null`, is where you should have the client-side `id` of the component you're looking to target
2. Specify the `for` attribute on the `message` component, limiting display of messages to that component only.

Putting it all together, you should now have

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Requests:Certificate1:downloadButton", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Please enter the Reference No."));
```

Where "downloadButton" is the `id` of the `<p:commandButton/>`

```
<p:messages for="downloadButton" id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>

<p:commandButton id="downloadButton" value="Download" ajax="false" actionListener="#{hrd.PDFSTAR}" >
      <p:fileDownload value="#{hrd.fileSTAR}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

**Unrelated to the actual problem**

There's no need to be using `<p:messages/>` in the dialog, if the message is to be displayed for a single component only - `<p:message/>` will work just as well